# What language analyzer to use at search time on language specific content (Elastic Search)?

Tags: elasticsearch

We have an application in which customers located in different countries (thus with different languages) can enter text blocks.  A text block is between 200 and 2.000 characters and the existing language detection algorithms are thus pretty accurate.  A text written in Dutch is thus analyzed with Dutch stop words and Dutch stemming. A French text with French stop words and French stemming. This is perfect.

We do not have an ES index per language. Thus in the same index there is a mixture of several languages, but each document is analyzed with the correct analyzer.

Here is my question: if we now want to search for a document (using a typical "google-style" search bar), the user enters a few words and based on these words we search in ES.  What analyzer should we use at search time ?  If a user only enters 2 or 3 words, language detection is not accurate, thus analyzing the text with such an in-accurate analyzer is not the solution I think ...  Analyzing with the default analyzer is also a problem because there is just a "word-split" and no stemming or other langauge specific tokenization.

Is there a best practice that you can recommend, resulting in accurate search results ?

Hope somebody can help.

Answer (score 1):

We were just recently tackling a very similar problem.

If I were to take a guess, you're probably analyzing your documents at index time by setting the `_analyzer` field in your document to the appropriate language analyzer in elasticsearch.

The problem with this approach is that elasticsearch doesn't check the analyzer defined in the document at query time. Elasticsearch has the capability to find the correct analyzer for the query by bubbling up the hierarchy  until it finds a defined analyzer:

First, it checks to see if there is:

- The `analyzer` defined in the query itself, else
- The `search_analyzer` defined in the field mapping, else
- The `analyzer` defined in the field mapping, else
- The `default` search_analyzer for the type, which defaults to
- The `default` analyzer for the type, which defaults to
- The analyzer named `default_search` in the index settings, which defaults to
- The analyzer named `default` in the index settings, which defaults to
- The analyzer named `default_search` at node level, which defaults to
- The analyzer named `default` at node level, which defaults to
- The `standard` analyzer

You can see here that the analyzer defined for the document is never checked. If you're able to designate one index per language, you benefit from the fact that:

- The correct analyzer to use on the language is decided for you automatically
- relevance is preserved. See http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/language-pitfalls.html#_at_index_time

Answer (score 0):

If you have the possibility to have the user locale (e.g. browser's locale), you may :

- use an index by language as suggested by tss.
- search for the term on multiple index/languages at once, but boosting some of them using `indices_boost` parameter. The boost candidates would be determined using the user locale.

For example, you may decide that for german users that Dutch should be queried too, but give less importance to these results. In this case, your user typing "Foutmelding" would still have some results.

```
{
  "query":{
    ...
  },
  "indices_boost":{
    "index-ge": 5,
    "index-nl": 1
  }
}
```

Downside is that you would have to decide of a "locale mapping" to define these boosts.

Comment: how can I achieve the indices_boost with the java client? It seems not possible.